# renaming mysql database without long-lasting dump?

Tags: mysql, database, rename

I've got a big database (mlns of records) and I need to rename it. So far I thought I'd have to dump it all and load into a new-named database. I've just found out there's a [RENAME DATABASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rename-database.html) statement in MySQL, but - according to the docs - *it was found to be dangerous and was removed in MySQL 5.1.23*. So I guess the only way is still to dump and load entire db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That sounds right. Taking a mysqldump and restoring it into a newly created DB is a quick way to rename or copy a database.

Comment: heh, the problem is that it's not a *quick* way ;)